# Alternating Row Color by number in a column

Tags: reporting-services

I have a columns with numbers that determine a job and suffix:

Example:

```
|Jobnumber|Suffix| 
  x001       1 - white
  x001       2 - grey
  x001       2 - grey
  x001       3 - white
  x002       1  <---- where it would break the alternating color, Should be grey!
  x002       1 - should be grey
  x002       1 - should be grey
  x002       2 - should be white
  x002       2 - should be white
  x003       1 - should be grey
```

I have the report set up to accept a range of `Jobnumbers` and a range of `Suffixes` so each `Jobnumber` has a set of suffixes ordered by ascending. I have the expression code alternate by the different `Suffix` numbers by color but it breaks when the next `Jobnumber` and `Suffix` is up next in the report.

How can I get the rows to still alternate by color when the next set of `Jobnumbers` and `Suffixes` come up in the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your alternating row colours to ignore the jobnumber and suffix then base your expression on ROWNUMBER instead Suffix.

e.g. `=IIF(ROWNUMBER(Nothing) MOD 2, "LightBlue", Nothing)`

**UPDATE: BASED ON REVISED QUESTION**

There may be a more elegant way of doing this but the following should work.

The first thing to do is go to the report properties and add two report variables to your report. Add `AltBackColour` with a value of `1` and `LastRownumber` with a value of `-1`. Switch off the read-only check box
[image]

Next, click on the Code tab add the following function.

```
Public Function BackColour (ByVal cuRowNumber AS Integer, ByVal lastJobNumber AS String, ByVal curJobNumber AS String, ByVal lastSuffix AS Integer, ByVal curSuffix AS Integer) as Integer
' Check if EITHER the job or suffix have changed, if so, switch the backcolour flag and update the report variable.

Dim switch as boolean
switch = ((lastJobNumber <> curJobNumber) or (lastSuffix <> curSuffix)) and cuRowNumber <> Report.Variables!LastRowNumber.Value

If Switch = true THEN 
    IF Report.Variables!AltBackColour.Value = 0 THEN 
        Report.Variables!AltBackColour.Value = 1 
    ELSE Report.Variables!AltBackColour.Value = 0
    END IF
End if

Report.Variables!LastRowNumber.Value = cuRowNumber

BackColour = Report.Variables!AltBackColour.Value 

End Function
```

Finally, set the `BackgroundColor` property of the row to the following expression.

```
=IIF(
    Code.BackColour(
                    RowNumber(Nothing)
                    , Previous(Fields!JobNumber.Value)
                    , Fields!JobNumber.Value
                    , Previous(Fields!Suffix.Value)
                    , Fields!Suffix.Value
                    ) = 0
    , Nothing
    , "LightGreen"
    )
```

I did this with your sample data and got the following result.

[image]

Basically the code checks to see if either the job of suffix have changed and switches a flag between 1 and 0 to indicate which colour to use. It also checks that we are not checking the same row as previously. We do this because even though we set the row's backcolor property, what actually happens is each cell gets is backcolor property set meaning the code gets called for each cell and will keep flipping the flag. By checking if the row has changed we get round this.

Comment: I want the alternating color to be dictated by the suffix but the next set of job numbers in the range also have suffixes associated with them and that's where the alternating row color breaks. just like in my original post Jobnumber x001 ends with the suffix associated "3" then Jobnumber x002 comes up next in the range and the suffix is re-sequenced back to 1 and that's where it breaks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean row one would be highlighted but rows 2 and 3 would not then row 4 would be highlighted etc? Can you edit your question and show the colours against each row of data so it's clear.

Comment: I fixed the example if you look at it where the arrow is the alternating color doesn't separate the suffixes when the Job number changes and the suffix is re-sequence.

Comment: I was just about to work on some similar custom code, but you seem to have nailed it first.  Would've been a lot easier if you could simply access the `Previous(Fields!Suffix.BackgroundColor)` but I think your update is the best possible way.

Comment: Yep, I'm sure there is a better way of doing this but this but I went round in circles for a while before settling on this approach. I don;t have enough brain power these days...